# Elasticsearch: type of fields in mapping is different from type in query result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index named attachment_test and the mapping is below:

[image]

I indexed it like use the json data below:

```
{"goods_id": 67,"sold_num_day90": "25","created_at": "1455575376","current_day": "20160215","sold_num_day3": "0","sold_num_day30": "15","sold_num_day7": "0"}
```

I searched and get the result:
[image]

These data are surrounded by quote except field goods_id. Why these string didn't transform to long automatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The source will always be returned exactly how you inputed in, i.e. the source is never transformed in any way by Elasticsearch.

However, ES will strive to coerce each field of that document to the type configured in your mapping and that coerced value will eventually be indexed into Lucene.

If you want those double quotes to disappear, just don't make them appear in the document you index.

Comment: Do you mean the quotes doesn't exist in Lucene in this scenarios? I am trying to index using data in HDFS files. These data can be any type.

Comment: The quotes are simply the JSON way to denote that you indexed a string value in your document. ES will take that string value (e.g. `"1455575376"`) and make its best to coerce that string value into the type you've declared in your mapping (e.g. a `long`). If it goes well, Lucene will index a long value, otherwise ES complains and throws an exception. So what you see in your source JSON and what is ultimately indexed in Lucene **can be** different. The best practice is to always create your JSON with the same types you declare in your mapping (i.e. in your case no quotes around long numbers).